# Answer Says $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6} = 0$. I say DNE. What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I was asked to find 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$$

Observe that setting y=mx results in $$\lim_{(x,mx)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3(mx)^2}{x^4+(mx)^6} = 0$$
The textbook solution then proved that the limit is 0 using the squeeze theorem.

However, I tried to set y=x^(4/6) and I got:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3(x^{\frac{4}{6}})^2}{x^4+(x^{\frac{4}{6}})^6} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^4}{x^4+x^4} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So I concluded that the limit does not exist. 
I am not convinced that my solution is correct, I would really appreciate to know the reason why I am wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't use display math (double dollar signs) in titles, it makes the frontpage very unsightly.

Comment: Yup, I'll be more careful from now on.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1442771/11619). I think the argument I proffered there is somehow more convincing than an attempt to use the polar coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful in your computations... $(x^{4/6})^2 = x^{4/3}$ and then $x^3 x^{4/3} = x^{13/3}$. The end result of the expression is $$\frac{x^{13/3}}{2x^4} = \frac{1}{2}x^{1/3}$$ which *does* converge to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$$\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}\stackrel{\text{Polar Coord.}}=\frac{r^5\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^4(\cos^4\theta+r^2\sin^6\theta)}=r\frac{\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^4\theta+r^2\sin^6\theta}\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$

Comment: What happens when the origin is approached along a path where $\cos\theta\to0$?  Then the denominator here goes to zero, potentially faster than the numerator, and it's not immediatly clear at all that the limit must be zero.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, in that case the numerator approaches zero whereas the denominator approaches $\;0+r^2\cdot 1\;$ , and in the overall the limit is zero... The numerator does *not* approach zero in this case.

Comment: Right, but we're also taking the limit as $r\to0$, remember, so the limit of $0+r^2\cdot1$ is also zero.  I just don't see how this gets you away from a $\frac00$ term at all.

Comment: Either the path where $\;\cos\theta\to 0\;$ is limited, and then we go by $\;r\;$, or else we stick on that path (say, $\;\theta=\frac\pi4\;$) , and then from the start we have zero..

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1442823/11619) Clark shows how to do this without any handwaving.

Comment: I ended up downvoting this. Your handwavy argument seems to suggest that $f(x,y)/r$ would be bounded near the origin. But, when $x=t^3, y=t^2$ we see that $f(x,y)=t/2$. In other words $f(x,y)$ can be as small as a constant times $\sqrt{r}$. Addressing @Steven's critic by talking about paths is unconvincing. One might think that you claim $f(x,y)/r$ to be bounded near the origin, which is false.